# Why does variable binding affect lifetime inside a loop body?

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex

In "The Rust Programming Language" in [chapter 20](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-00-final-project-a-web-server.html) you go through an exercise of building a simple multi-threaded web server. In the exercise you use a single `std::sync::mpsc` channel. The worker threads all access a single Receiver which is contained like: `Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Message>>>`.

If we write the worker thread like:

```
let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
    match receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap() {
        Message::NewJob(job) => {
            println!("Worker {} got a job; executing.", id);

            job.call_box();

            println!("Worker {} job complete.", id);
        }
        Message::Terminate => {
            println!("Worker {} was told to terminate.", id);

            break;
        }
    };
    println!("hello, loop");
});
```

Then we do not achieve concurrency, *apparently* the worker holds on to the mutex lock I supposed because no worker is able to pull off another job until the previous one is complete. However if we simply change it to this (how the book shows the code):

```
let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
    let message = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();

    match message {
        Message::NewJob(job) => {
            println!("Worker {} got a job; executing.", id);

            job.call_box();

            println!("Worker {} job complete.", id);
        }
        Message::Terminate => {
            println!("Worker {} was told to terminate.", id);

            break;
        }
    };
    println!("hello, loop");
});
```

Then everything works fine. If you fire off 5 requests you'll see each thread gets one immediately. Concurrency!

The question is "why does variable binding affect lifetime" (I'm assuming that's the reason). Or if not then I'm missing something and what is that?! The book itself talks about how you cannot implement the worker loop with `while let Ok(job) = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv() {` because of the scope of the lock but apparently even *inside* the loop there be dragons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in Rust, ["resource acquisition is initialization"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/raii.html).

Specifically [`receiver.lock()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.lock) returns a type which acquires the lock when it is initialized and releases the lock when it is dropped.

In your first example, the lifetime of the `MutexGuard` extends to the end of the `match` statement, so the lock will be held while `job.call_box()` is called.

```
match receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap() {
    // ...
};
// `MutexGuard` is dropped and lock is released here
```

In your second example, the lock guard is only kept alive long enough to read a message from your message queue; the lock guard is dropped at the end of the statement and the lock is released before the `match` is entered.

```
let message = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
// `MutexGuard` is dropped and lock is released here

match message {
```

Comment: Yes thanks! Hehe I just now was explaining the problem I saw to someone else and as I was explaining it I realized that I can't think of match as having the match expression and then blocks inside as different "statements", an entire match can function as an expression so the lifetime of all those objects will extend until the whole match is finished. Thanks for your well-written explanation.